# Command Line - bool argument doesn't work

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments, command-line-parser

I am trying to use bool argument in my console application. I'm using the [CommandLineParser](https://commandline.codeplex.com/) Package, but parser return error.

this is my option

```
    [Option("randomize", Required = false, DefaultValue = false, HelpText = "Enter \"true\" for the random selection")]
    public bool Randomize { get; set; }
```

argument: `--randomize=true`

I am using `Parser.Default.ParseArguments`

Any idea why this doesn't work?

Comment: This is not standard C#. I guess you are using a library for this? Please post a [mcve].

Comment: no, I use [link](https://commandline.codeplex.com/)

Comment: So you *do* use a library. That's not a bad thing, but you need to mention it. And we still need a [mcve].

Comment: We also need to know **which** error the parser returned.

Comment: I don't see any sample in the documentation that would suggest to write `--randomize=true` - all I found used something along the lines of `--randomize` to set the boolean value to true.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to add `true` or `false` as the argument value - CommandLineParser will just set the value to `true` *if the argument is present*.

So this will pass in a value of true:

```
--randomize
```

So if your application is called `ParserApp` the following passes `true`

```
ParserApp --randomize
```

While the below line will pass `false`

```
ParserApp
```

The [Quick Start guide](https://github.com/gsscoder/commandline/wiki/Quickstart) has an example for the usage of a boolean parameter.

Comment: So it looks like setting `DefaultValue = true` in the `Option` attribute for a `bool` option would make it such that the option could never be set to `false` when executing? Since `--randomize=false` can't be parsed, as mentioned.